# "Update Integer Value" function not fully accurate

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript function to track/update the number of files within a folder. It is pretty accurate most of the time, but has around a 10% margin of error. I think it has to do with the 'totalItemCount' variable not being updated properly. I have looked for hours but can't find where I may have messed up. It's a long file but really all you have to look at is the 'totalItemCount' var

```
new ApiClient({
    //marketing (69 Files, 40 Folders, 109 total, 204MB): 7f6d706e-6754-e411-b5b8-d4ae5294c399
    //tgsr/...governence (1,302 Files, 130 Folders, 1432 total): bba3bd73-f855-e411-b5b8-d4ae5294c399
    //infrastructureSoftware(): 7009c1d2-7e67-e511-80cc-000af7703bc2
    //  HELM Platform: bbab7b02-4e39-4287-abd2-445688cf4fb1

    //bbl... 6ce640d2-722f-48b4-a1de-7a059305b6c3
    apimethod: 'objects/95750c6b-84f5-4587-8b86-b559551f7660/children/view',
    method: 'get',
    queryparams: {
        maxcount: 8000,
        startindex: 0,
        includefuturepublished: true
    },
    onSuccess: function (responseText) 
    {
        var result = JSON.parse(responseText);
        var originalObject = result; //first, top-level object
        var totalItemCount = 0;
        var filesize = 0;

        totalItemCount += parseInt(result.response.totalCount);

        //Check if object has children and add to totalItemCount accordingly FOR EACH object:

        function getItemsRecursively(totalItemCount1, filesize1)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(totalItemCount); i++) //at this point, totalCount == #objects at this lvl
            {
                var currentObject = result.response.items[i];

                if(currentObject.size != undefined)
                {
                    filesize += currentObject.size;
                    filesize1 = filesize;
                }


                if(currentObject.numchildren > 0 && currentObject.numchildren != undefined)
                {
                    getChildrenItemCount(totalItemCount1, currentObject, filesize1);
                }

            }
        }

        function getChildrenItemCount(totalItemCount2, previousObject, filesize2)
        {
            //totalItemCount2 = totalItemCount;
            var childID = previousObject.id;
            new ApiClient
            ({
                apimethod: 'objects/' + childID + '/children/view',
                method: 'get',
                queryparams: {
                    maxcount: 8000,
                    startindex: 0,
                    includefuturepublished: true
                },
                onSuccess: function (responseText) 
                {
                    var result = JSON.parse(responseText);
                    var currentObject = result.response;

                    var currentFolderItemCount = currentObject.totalCount;

                    for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(currentFolderItemCount); i++) //at this point, totalCount == #objects at this lvl
                    {
                        var currentObject = result.response.items[i];

                        if(currentObject.size != undefined)
                        {
                            filesize += currentObject.size;
                            filesize2 = filesize;
                        }

                        if(currentObject.numchildren > 0 && currentObject.numchildren != undefined)
                        {
                            totalItemCount += parseInt(currentObject.numchildren);
                            totalItemCount2 = totalItemCount;
                            getChildrenItemCount(totalItemCount2, currentObject, filesize2);
                        }

                        //var filesize = currentObject.size;

                    }
                }
            })
        }

        getItemsRecursively(totalItemCount, filesize);

    }
})
```

Comment: could do reduce your code to the smallest version that replicates the issue (i.e. a [mcve]) - also, what's the input look like and what's the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

*I can't comment with my current rep, so sorry to SO community for posting as an answer.*

It would be nice to see how `totalCount` is being set (where it says `result.response.totalCount`).

Also, I recommend taking out all the `console.log`'s. It makes it very hard to read your code.

If a folder contains a folder, does that qualify as a file for you? If so, do you have that logic in your code?

I'd be glad to take another look once you update with what I suggested.

**Update:** Try this code. I couldn't test, so you'll have let me know how it works.

```
var totalItemCount;
new ApiClient({
apimethod: 'objects/95750c6b-84f5-4587-8b86-b559551f7660/children/view',
method: 'get',
queryparams: {
    maxcount: 8000,
    startindex: 0,
    includefuturepublished: true
},
onSuccess: function (responseText) {

    var result = JSON.parse(responseText);
    totalItemCount = parseInt(result.response.totalCount);

    getItemsRecursively();
}
});

function getItemsRecursively() {

    for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(totalItemCount); i++) {

        var currentObject = result.response.items[i];

        if(currentObject.size != undefined) {
            filesize += currentObject.size;

            if(currentObject.numchildren > 0 && currentObject.numchildren != undefined) {
                getChildrenItemCount(currentObject);
            }

        }
    }
}



function getChildrenItemCount(previousObject) {
    var childID = previousObject.id;
    new ApiClient
    ({
        apimethod: 'objects/' + childID + '/children/view',
        method: 'get',
        queryparams: {
            maxcount: 8000,
            startindex: 0,
            includefuturepublished: true
        },
        onSuccess: function (responseText) 
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var currentFolderItemCount = result.response.totalCount;

            for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(currentFolderItemCount); i++) 
            {
                var currentObject = result.response.items[i];

                if(currentObject.numchildren > 0 && currentObject.numchildren != undefined)
                {
                    totalItemCount += parseInt(currentObject.numchildren);
                    getChildrenItemCount(currentObject);
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, if a folder contains a folder it counts as an 'item' and is added to the totalItemCount var. The totalCount is from the Igloo API which I am using. totalCount is the number of items in the current directory. I have taken the console.log's out of my code if you want to take another look, i'd appreciate it!

Comment: For this code `getChildrenItemCount(totalItemCount2, currentObject, filesize2);`, it looks like you are trying to pass only the current objects count, but if I'm correct, you are passing your `totalItemCount`(your running total). Also, in your `getItemsRecursively` function, your call to the function `getChildrenItemCount` should return the count and add it to `totalItemCount`. It doesn't seem to do that, which means your children counts are not being included.

Comment: I do mean to pass in my totalItemCount (running total) so that the running total can be updated within getChildren(). And if my children counts were not being included there would be much more than a 10% margin of error because some folders contain sub folders of sub folders of sub folders etc.

Comment: Also, looking back through the code I posted. I'm not even utilizing the variables `filesize*`. Was this just for you to reference when using `console.log`?